# Cesium vs WebGL Earth JS

Tags: cesium

I read about WebGL Earth that it uses under the hood the great CesiumJS project for the rendering of the data.

But exactly, for a developer, what are main differences between CesiumJS and WebGL Earth ?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer, I'm a Cesium contributor and I haven't worked directly with WebGL Earth.

As mentioned in the documentation, all of WebGL Earth's rendering is handled by Cesium under the hood.  From their documentation it looks like it makes an attempt to be API-compatible with Leaflet, such that WebGL Earth could be considered nearly a drop-in replacement for an existing Leaflet map.

As such the WebGL Earth API appears to be much simpler, but much more limited, than the Cesium API.  All of Cesium's time-varying properties are removed from WebGL Earth, so for example you can't show an aircraft flying or a satellite orbiting the way you can in Cesium.

Also it appears that many of the WebGL Earth examples are using a pretty old version of Cesium.  On the page `webglearth.com` you can hit F12 to open a web console and type `Cesium.VERSION` to see it's using version 1.14, which was released October 2015, almost 2 years out of date as of this writing.  A lot of bug fixes, including support for newer mobile devices, have been merged into Cesium since then.